# regex for finding outermost sequences

Tags: c#, regex

My special html sequence. I want to match region and destination foreach Blocks until }@. Subregion is a nested sequence and should be excluded.

```
@foreach(region){
    @foreach(subregion){
        @{subregion.name}
    }@
}@
@foreach(destination){
    @{destination.name}
}@
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `I want to` is not a question.

Comment: did you want to check for nested paranthesis?

Comment: @Jonesy I want to => How to

Comment: regex should have two matches:
- @foreach(region){ ... }@
- @foreach(destination){ ... }@

Comment: This is my current regex (not fully functional):
(([@]foreach)[(](.*?|\b)[)]{)(.*)(}@)(.*?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use balanced groups:

```
@foreach\([^)]*\)\s*{(?>(?<open>@foreach\([^)]*\)\s*{)|@{[^}]*}|[^}@]+|(?<-open>}@))*(?(open)(?!))}@
```

The idea is to define a named capture that works like a counter. When an opening substring is found, the counter is incremented, when a closing substring is found the counter is decremented. `(?(open)(?!))` forces the pattern to fail if the counter is not null.

```
@foreach\([^)]*\)\s*{
(?> # possible content in a foreach
    (?<open>@foreach\([^)]*\)\s*{) # increment the counter
  |
    @{[^}]*} 
  |
    [^}@]+   # all that is not a @ or } (can be improved to be more flexible)
  |
    (?<-open>}@) # decrement the counter
)*
(?(open)     # conditional statement (if "open" is not null)
    (?!)     # then make fail the pattern (with the always false assertion `(?!)`)
)
}@
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%40foreach%5c(%5b%5e)%5d*%5c)%5cs*%7b(%3f%3e(%3f%3copen%3e%40foreach%5c(%5b%5e)%5d*%5c)%5cs*%7b)%7c%40%7b%5b%5e%7d%5d*%7d%7c%5b%5e%7d%40%5d%2b%7c(%3f%3c-open%3e%7d%40))*(%3f(open)(%3f!))%7d%40&i=%40foreach(region)%7b%0d%0a++++%40foreach(subregion)%7b%0d%0a++++++++%40%7bsubregion.name%7d%0d%0a++++%7d%40%0d%0a%7d%40%0d%0a%0d%0aabcde%0d%0a%0d%0a%40foreach(destination)%7b%0d%0a++++%40%7bdestination.name%7d%0d%0a%7d%40)

Comment: Wauw, just want i needed :)

Comment: @Casimir could you provide a link for online c# regex tester? I need to test your regex ...

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I have added a link.

Comment: @Rawling: There are at least three regex tester for .net: http://regexstorm.net/tester, http://regexplanet.com and http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: In the solution on the line that can be improved, is it possible to match all thats not @foreach\([^)]*\)\s*{ and }@